# Installing Ubuntu on a SSD+HDD setup

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

Can someone can guide me as to how to install on an ssd+hdd setup? I couldn't find a specific question that answers my query so I apologize if I'm being redundant.

I have a 250GBssd + 2TBhdd setup. I'd like to know how to install Ubuntu on one of the drives. Is it more advantageous to installing it on the ssd? I'd like the windows to go on the ssd as well. Please guide me so as to install it in the most optimal way possible.

B) I heard concerns regarding life of ssd with Ubuntu on it so I'm not so sure.

C) I have an AMD ryzen CPU + Nvidia 10 series GPU and I also heard driver support for Nvidia cards are not so strong. Nvidia doesn't have official Linux drivers for the 10 series cards so if possible I'd like to know how to go about this issue too.

Comment: Click on the grey EDIT link above left to edit & remove the questions regarding SSD life and Nvidia drivers. Site guidelines call for one major issue per post, and it sure makes it easier to answer one issue at a time.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu and https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/ are still valid even though they discuss earlier version of Windows.  Also,I suggest using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which you didn't mention above; it's customary to mention which Ubuntu version you instend to work with.

Comment: B) SSDs are AOK in Ubuntu: See https://www.pcworld.com/article/2856052/grueling-endurance-test-blows-away-ssd-durability-fears.html https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/06/consumer-grade-ssds-actually-last-a-hell-of-a-long-time/ https://lifehacker.com/how-long-will-my-hard-drives-really-last-1700405627  and those are with older designs; modern designs are even better. Anything electronic will fail sooner or later; just make backups.

Comment: C) http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/111596/en-us shows there's support for many 10 series Nvidia cards, i.e., desktop GTX 1080, 1070, 1060, 1050 Ti, 1050, and laptop GTX 1080, 1070, and 1060. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia provides instructions.

Comment: No issues with nVidia support. But depending on version of Ryzen chip, you may need newer kernel & support software than is currently standard in 18.04. Asus B350M-A needs newer kernel that 18.04 default
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391892
Raven Ridge With The Ryzen 5 2400G On Mesa 18.2 + Linux 4.17 Is Finally Stable MSI B350M GAMING PRO
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ryzen-2400g-may&num=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Windows first; it's far easier to install Ubuntu after Windows.

The [newer and easier](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737686/ubuntu-installation-uefi-partitioning-skylake-and-nvidia) to work with [EFI/UEFI partitioning with GPT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-uefi-mode-or-legacy-bios-mode) is [preferred to MBR formatting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647922/problem-with-dual-booting-ubuntu-14-04-2-and-windows-7-x64-ultimate/648702#648702) since MBR drives are limited in the number of primary partitions, and Windows 10 wants multiple partitions. Have Windows format the HDD as NTFS, as [Ubuntu reads/writes NTFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504080/will-i-be-able-to-use-my-ntfs-data-partition-in-ubuntu) (the native Windows SSD/HDD format), whereas [Windows requires special drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows) to read/write ext4 (the native Ubuntu format).

Just [put Windows on the SSD](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/), then [put Ubuntu on it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot), too; Ubuntu will repartition the SSD to make space for itself. You can [adjust the sizes later](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions).